# What is the name of the design pattern where a method invocation cancels a previous invocation?

Tags: design-patterns

I have an auto-complete textbox whereby a search is invoked as the user types text into the textbox.  If another search is triggered, a previously invoked search is cancelled.

What is the name of this design pattern?

Comment: There is no such programming pattern. You just cancel any previously triggered executions.

Comment: A form of a cancellation pattern, then?  If it's a pattern, there should be a name.

Comment: As said above: there is no such pattern. Patterns are only recognized if they describe some non trivial implementation, so something much more complex than the task you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a design pattern but I've seen it beeing called a 'delayed trigger'. Basically you schedule the search task to run after a delay and if new search comes in just cancel the previous task.

Comment: A design pattern is a design that is common enough to be considered a pattern.  I suppose this pattern is just unnamed yet.  Thanks for the suggestion.  It gave me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to undo an operation is typically associated with the [Command pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command). Undo can be invoked explicitly (for example using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) but in this case your code would invoke undo implicitly in response to a subsequent operation.